# Muting system volume upon logout using launch agent

Tags: macos, launchd, sound-volume

I'm attempting to create a script for muting the system volume which gets triggered upon logging out or shutting down. This is to avoid hearing the startup chime really loudly the next time I start the machine.

Using the instructions provided in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/151492/260152), I have created a `RunAtLoad` launch agent that calls the script shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

IFS=$'\n\t'

onLogout ()
{
    osascript -e "set volume output volume 0"
    exit
}

trap onLogout SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM

while true; do
    say starting
    sleep 86400 &
    wait $!
done
```

The idea being that the script is called and made to sleep until it receives one of the trapped signals, at which point the `onLogout` function is called in order to mute the volume.

Currently it's not working as intended, the volume remains unchanged when I log out and log back in. However, I've found that if I manually unload the launch agent that launches the script (using a `launchctl unload` call), then it works perfectly. The system volume is muted immediately.

Initially I thought perhaps the trapped signals weren't being received by the script when I performed a logout. But after adding some debugging code to the `onLogout` function as shown below, I have eliminated this as a possible cause.

```
onLogout ()
{
    printf "Before mute\n" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
    osascript -e "set volume output volume 0"
    printf "After mute\n" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
    exit
}
```

When I performed a logout, and logged back in, there was a `"log.txt"` file on the desktop with both of the `Before mute` and `After mute` debugging lines present.

And I don't believe the reason is that the `osascript` call for performing the muting is somehow failing when a logout is carried out. Due to the `set -o errexit` line in the script, if any part of the script fails, then it should halt execution and exit immediately. This means that if the muting operation is failing, I shouldn't be seeing the `After muting` line in my log file. Indeed, when I tested this by replacing the `osascript` line with something I knew was guaranteed to fail, the log contained only the `Before muting` line as expected.

I'm at a loss to explain what's going on. Clearly the `onLogout` function is being called correctly as explained above, but for some reason the `osascript` call seems to only run when I manually unload using `launchctl`. When I log out manually it just skips over it somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal, execute the following command to disable the chime completely until reenabled:

`sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80`

If this setting is not retained, try:

`sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01`

`sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00`

or

`sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume="  "`

To reenable the chime:

`sudo nvram -d SystemAudioVolume`

Info gleaned from:

https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-silence-the-startup-chime-on-a-mac--cms-21212

https://www.howtogeek.com/260693/how-to-disable-the-boot-sound-or-startup-chime-on-a-mac/

Comment: This works. Most of the time. I have this value set and was greeted this morning with a booming chime noise. Can you specify when this value gets overridden or ignored?

Comment: Hmmm. It should stay with that setting. I've added other commands to my answer to try if %80 doesn't work.

Comment: At one point or another I tried them all. nvram -p currently lists %80. The last dozn or so boots were silent. They all seem to be working only 99% percent of time. What about SystemAudioVolumeDB? That value changes arbitrarily.

Comment: What version of OS X / macOS are you folks running? I can't get this to work on Sierra. I've tried all of the variations for values (`%80`, `%01`, `%00`, `" "`), but I get the chime each time. `%80` seems to be the magic value though, since when I manually mute the system volume and then restart (which so far is the only surefire way to have no chime), `nvram` reports `%80` for both `SystemAudioVolume` and `SystemAudioVolumeDB`. But the problem is that these values get reset to `:` and `%e4` respectively whenever I restart or shutdown without having first muted the volume myself.